# Getting No module named 'rds_config' when I try to test locally lambda function that has to connect to RDS

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

This is my code , I am getting No module named 'rds_config' when I run it locally.
Can I do that or I have to test it in AWS?

```
import sys
import logging 
import rds_config 
import pymysql 
import requests 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
now = datetime.now()

logger = logging.getLogger() logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=name, passwd=password, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5) except pymysql.MySQLError as e:
    logger.error("ERROR: Unexpected error: Could not connect to MySQL instance.")
    logger.error(e)
    sys.exit()

logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS MySQL instance succeeded")

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: Where is your rds_config.py file?

Comment: thank you for your question.It is my first time doing a lambda and I did not know I have to have rds_config.py . I will look into it